# Nx fails to work entirely -No projects have an target command for run-

Tags: javascript, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I have tried using NX extention on vscode, it fails. Using  commans on terminal also fails with the error  -Daemon process terminated and closed the connection-.

I've tried adding `useDaemonProcess: false` to my `nx.json`, it didn't change and I have also tried `nx reset`, didnt work either.